# How to subscribe to Shopware 5 plugin config value changes?

Tags: shopware, shopware5

is it possible to execute some code, e.g. via a subscriber action to my Shopware 5 plugin config changes?

Is there a backend Pre/Post dispatch event for it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your requirements you can use `Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Config_Before_Save_Config_Element` or `Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Config_After_Save_Config_Element` event.
If you need to get new values `Shopware_Controllers_Backend_Config_After_Save_Config_Element` looks like better for your case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [shopware documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-guidelines/#clearing-the-cache-when-configuration-changes) you can use `Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Backend_Config`